# TIA Bloomberg converting from Excel Formulas - BDS() Bulk Data

Tags: python, bloomberg

https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ if you look at the `BLPAPI Core Developer Guide` under `15.3 BDS(): BULK DATA (STATIC)`, the guide shows you a very simple `BDS()` conversion.

I'm trying to get the segment data. And this is the Excel formula I'm trying to convert:
`BDS("MSFT","PG_REVENUE","PG_HIERARCHY_LEVEL=1","NUMBER_OF_PERIODS=-11","REVERSE_PERIOD_ORDER=N","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=P","FUND_PER","FQ")`

Here is my code:

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

ticker=['MSFT US Equity']
overrides=["PG_HIERARCHY_LEVEL=1","PRODUCT_GEO_OVERRIDE=P",'FUND_PER','FQ']

resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(ticker,"PG_REVENUE",overrides)
a=resp.as_map()
```

It seems no matter what I put into the `overrides` variable. I get the same output.

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'MSFT US Equity': {'PG_REVENUE':                             Metric Name  Product Geographic Hierarchy Level  \
0               More Personal Computing                                   1   
1   Productivity and Business Processes                                   1   
2                     Intelligent Cloud                                   1   
3                   Corporate and other                                   1   
4                            Commercial                                   1   
5                      Commercial Other                                   2   
6                  Commercial Licensing                                   2   
7                 Devices and Consumers                                   1   
8                           D & C Other                                   2   
9                        D & C Hardware                                   2   
10                      D & C Licensing                                   2   

    Period 1 Value  Period 2 Value  Period 3 Value  Period 4 Value  \
0     4.046000e+04    4.316000e+04    3.840700e+04   -2.424536e-14   
1     2.648700e+04    2.643000e+04    2.697200e+04   -2.424536e-14   
2     2.504200e+04    2.371500e+04    2.173200e+04   -2.424536e-14   
3    -6.669000e+03    2.750000e+02   -2.780000e+02    4.030000e+02   
4    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    4.534600e+04   
5    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    5.660000e+03   
6    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    3.968600e+04   
7    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    3.210000e+04   
8    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    6.618000e+03   
9    -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    6.461000e+03   
10   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14   -2.424536e-14    1.902100e+04   

    Period 5 Value  
0    -2.424536e-14  
1    -2.424536e-14  
2    -2.424536e-14  
3    -4.850000e+02  
4     4.177000e+04  
5     4.644000e+03  
6     3.712600e+04  
7     3.243800e+04  
8     6.203000e+03  
9     6.740000e+03  
10    1.949500e+04  }})
```

I'm not sure how to get the output on a quarterly basis.

Comment: Have you tried with `'FUND_PER=FQ'` instead of `'FUND_PER','FQ'`?

Comment: @assylias. yes I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't have to use the quotation marks for the overrides.

> `overrides=[PG_HIERARCHY_LEVEL=1]`

See the example jupyter notebook from the tia GitHub page:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bpsmith/tia/blob/master/examples/v3api.ipynb